# Add Timestamp dates to X for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

This loop use np for adding future dates to prediction dataset:

```
# Future prediction, add dates here for which you want to predict
dates = ["2021-12-23", "2022-12-24", "2023-12-25", "2024-12-26", "2025-12-27",]
#convert to time stamp
for dt in dates:
  datetime_object = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d")
  timestamp = datetime.timestamp(datetime_object)
  # to array X
  print(int(timestamp))
  np.append(X, int(timestamp))
```

it's return this values properly:

```
1640214000
1671836400
1703458800
1735167600
1766790000
```

---

The problem the code doesn't append these 5 timestamp values to array X (the hypothesis is that e+09 - notation - but don't have an idea how to make it work).

The structure of array X is:

```
array([[1.5383520e+09],
       [1.5384384e+09],
       [1.5385248e+09],
       (...)
       [1.6339968e+09],
       [1.6340832e+09],
       [1.6341696e+09]])
```

---

After add those timestamp values to X get the error in predicting code:

```
# Future prediction, add dates here for which you want to predict
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Define model
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
# Fit to model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
# predict
predictions = model.predict(X)
print(mean_squared_error(Y, predictions))
```

error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [766, 771]
```

in the last line

There is error - cause the X and Y values are different:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (771, 1) and (766, 1)
```

but already those 5 values from Y should be predicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside loop use this:

```
X = np.append(X, int(timestamp))
```

Comment: It's work but after further processing i gets -> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Comment: What kind of further processing and which line gives the error?

Comment: Ok - i just reshape that data structure - to fix that array dimension problem - but already now it's problem with samples:

Comment: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [766, 771]

Comment: I'm sorry I am not getting you. Does the loop execute successfully? and do you get those 5 dates in X?

Comment: yes, that's worked - thank U